# New Command in Menu of Tkinter not rerunning

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a TKinter App and tried to add a menu with "File"-> "New"

The Menu is another file called Menu.py which is being imported and created a new objected in the main program
I have 2 questions

1. What is the efficient method to call the "New" function from menu which runs the main program and creates another window(i have coded for it , but it is not right)
2. As the command for the "New" is in the init function , it only initialises it once(which means only the first time , the new window is created when clicked) , if i close the newly opened window, it does not work again.

Expectation:
I want an efficient way to call the New function.
I want it working everytime the "New" button from the app is called.

Code below:

#Tkinter_Main -> Main Program

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from Menu import menu

root= Tk()
menu_new = menu(root) 


root.mainloop()
```

#Menu.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk



class menu():
    def __init__(self,root):
        root.title('Demo')

        # create a menubar
        self.menubar = Menu(root)
        root.config(menu=self.menubar)

        self.file_menu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=False)

        # add the File menu to the menubar
        self.menubar.add_cascade(
            label="File",
            menu=self.file_menu
        )
        self.file_menu.add_command(
                label='New',
                command= menu.new_win
            )


    def new_win():
        import Tkinter_new
        Tkinter_new
```

Comment: FYI: you don't need both `from tkinter import *` and `from tkinter import Tk` - really you should [avoid star imports](https://code-maven.com/python-avoid-importing-everything) and instead use `import tkinter as tk`, then prefix any tkinter classes/methods with `tk.` appropriately. You also have some duplicate imports here (i.e., you've done `from tkinter import *` twice. And imports really should be at the top of the file, so `import Tkinter_new` (whatever that is) should be moved

Comment: @JRiggles Yes i will remove the duplicate imports. But i cant remove the import Tkinter_new and move it to the top as it will form a cyclic imports and wont allow it. So i have to use it in the function

Comment: If you're seeing a cyclic import error, that's usually indicative of some other issue with how your project is structured. Top level (in this case, GUI) code should exist in one module, and only supporting classes/methods should be imported into it.

Comment: @JRiggles Right . That too was one part of question as to what is the efficient method to do this. Because i am writing all part of menu code in another file. Maybe it is wrong. So please suggest

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand your question, you want to create a new window on the click of a button. I was not so sure about the filesystem, so here is just an idea for opening multiple windows on the click of a button either from the main window or the "file_menu":

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Main - dont close")


def setup_window(window):
    menubar = Menu(window)
    window.config(menu=menubar)

    file_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
    menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)
    file_menu.add_command(label='New', command=create_new_window)


def create_new_window():
    menu_new = Toplevel()
    menu_new.title("This is your new window")
    setup_window(menu_new)


setup_window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps you out, if you have any further questions please let me know, I will try to answer them...

Comment: Hi , this is working but the first main screen is without a file-> menu.
The file-> menu is appearing only after the first button click right?
I want the menu to be present from the start of a app.
Like in any application which you have in your pc. Once you open a software, the menu is present from the start and if you press the file-> new, a new window of the same software appears.

Comment: I edited the code, and added the feature that you can open a new window from the main window. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: I understand you have created the file and new seperately in the command function. But i want a new window with all the functionalities from the main window, i cannot keep writing everything twice right(In other words to run the main function again)

Comment: You can put the creation of the menu in a function, I will change the answer, I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Since module will be imported only once, so `import Tkinter_new` inside `new_win()` function will be executed once.

You can put the main code of `Tkinter_new.py` inside a function and import that function and execute it inside `new_win()` instead.

Below is the modified `Tkinter_new.py`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from Menu import menu

def main():
    root = Tk()
    menu_new = menu(root) 
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Below is the modified `Menu.py`:

```py
from tkinter import *

class menu():
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title('Demo')

        # create a menubar
        self.menubar = Menu(root)
        root.config(menu=self.menubar)

        self.file_menu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=False)

        # add the File menu to the menubar
        self.menubar.add_cascade(
            label="File",
            menu=self.file_menu
        )
        self.file_menu.add_command(
                label='New',
                command=self.new_win
            )

    def new_win(self):
        from Tkinter_new import main
        main()
```

Comment: importing another file in the function instead on the start is not a good way of writing ,which i made the mistake and want help. Any ideas to deviate that?